# Linux libs on freebsd (ibm_db libdb2.so.1)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, informix, freebsd

Im trying to use a lib on bsd that was designed for linux for IBM-db connections:

I have installed as per the ibmdocs for linux, and placed the required linux libs in /compat/linux/lib/

But i get the import error:

```
>>> import ibm_db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: Shared object "libdb2.so.1" not found, required by "ibm_db.so"
```

If I place the file manually in /usr/lib or symlink it I get a read error:

```
>>> import ibm_db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/lib/libdb2.so.1: Undefined symbol "strcspn"
```

If anyone could help on this I would be forever grateful!!

I have installed ibm_db and both ibm_db_sa without failure, I just think its more of an issue trying to use the linux app on bsd.

Comment: Just to make sure, you mean `/compat/linux/lib/`, not `/compact/linux/lib/`, right? If not, that would be your problem.

Comment: `strcspn()` is a standard C string function. It's as if libdb2.so.1 isn't linked to the standard library.

Comment: Yes sorry /compat/linux/lib and I am running freebsd and python is 2.7.2 inside a virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's looking for libraries in /usr/lib, you seem to be running the FreeBSD version of Python.

Since FreeBSD's Linux compatibility is a *per process* compatibility, you cannot load Linux libraries into a FreeBSD process. If you want to dynamically load Linux libraries, you need to run a Linux version of Python.

Comment: Can I do that within a virtualenv?

Comment: @Crooksey As far as I know, you need to install a totally separate Linux Python package. You should be able to run virtualenv just as well using the Linux version of Python though.